# Expansion and pronunciation of "Mrs"

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs.) says it used to stand for *mistress*. But you don't read it as *mistress*, do you?

What is the pronunciation like? I think it would depend on the expansion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The title Mrs. is pronounced /ˈmɪsɪz/ (MISS-iz). It is not ever spelled out to anything in formal contexts.

In informal contexts, it is often spelled out as “missus”. There are 258 incidences of “missus” in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/), nearly all in fiction, except for a handful in quotations in magazine and newspaper articles.

Comment: +1 for the link to the Corpus of Contemporary American English, nice resource

Answer (score 6):

It is pronounced "misses", though there is no standard expansion that I am aware of. Its meaning now derives from tradition rather than from any word it might stand for.